# Material UI - FormLabel not highlighted with custom control in FormGroup

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have used a custom control (a sortable list using [react-dnd](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about)) inside a FormGroup. The issue is that the FormLabel which has the question is not getting focused with this custom control.

```
<FormControl fullWidth>
    <FormLabel required={required}>{question}</FormLabel>
    <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
        <FormGroup>
        {cards.map((card, i) => (
            <FormControlLabel key={i} control={renderCard(card, i)}/>
        ))}
        </FormGroup>
    </DndProvider>
</FormControl>
```

The focus works with a CheckBox as control inside the FormGroup as expected.

```
<FormControl>
    <FormLabel required={required}>{question}</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup>
    {options.map(option => (
        <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox onChange={handleChange} name={option}/>} label={option} />
    ))}
    </FormGroup>
</FormControl>
```

Can someone please help me with what I am missing here? Thanks!